# Yajra DataTable is not populating/Search for an easier way for search in tables and print to pdf function (Laravel)

Tags: php, laravel, datatables, laravel-8, yajra-datatable

I want to display a DataTable of job applications with an application_status_id of 8, meaning completed applications where the jobseeker has been deployed. I'm very new to DataTables in Laravel and PHP, and I've only been following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZqPzSIK2N-Y
However, Nothing's showing up, only the table headings.

I'm also having trouble on how I can display column data that are related to another table, which are

```
application_status_id = jobApplication->step->name
jobseeker_id = jobApplication->jobseeker->getFullNameAttribute()
jobpost_id = jobApplication->jobPost->job_position
```

jobApplicationDataTable

```
class jobApplicationDataTable extends DataTable
{
    /**
     * Build DataTable class.
     *
     * @param mixed $query Results from query() method.
     * @return \Yajra\DataTables\DataTableAbstract
     */
    public function dataTable($query)
    {
        return datatables()
            ->eloquent($query)
            ->addColumn('action', 'jobapplication.action');
    }

    /**
     * Get query source of dataTable.
     *
     * @param \App\Models\jobApplication $model
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder
     */
    public function query(jobApplication $model)
    {
        return $model->newQuery()->where('application_status_id','=',8)->with(['step','jobseeker','jobPost']);
    }

    /**
     * Optional method if you want to use html builder.
     *
     * @return \Yajra\DataTables\Html\Builder
     */
    public function html()
    {
        return $this->builder()
                    ->setTableId('jobapplication-table')
                    ->columns($this->getColumns())
                    ->minifiedAjax()
                    ->orderBy(1)
                    ->buttons(
                        // Button::make('create'),
                        Button::make('export'),
                        Button::make('print'),
                        // Button::make('reset'),
                        // Button::make('reload')
                    );
    }

    /**
     * Get columns.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    protected function getColumns()
    {
        return [
            // Column::computed('action')
            //       ->exportable(false)
            //       ->printable(false)
            //       ->width(60)
            //       ->addClass('text-center'),
            'id',
            'name' => new \Yajra\DataTables\Html\Column(['title' => "Applicant Name",'data' => 'jobseeker.getFullNameAttribute','name' => 'jobseeker'])
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Get filename for export.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    protected function filename()
    {
        return 'jobApplication_' . date('YmdHis');
    }
```

web.php

```
Route::get('/employee/fordeployment',[employeeController::class,'viewDeployedApplicants'])->middleware(['auth','employee'])->name('deployed-list');
```

Controller:

```
    public function viewDeployedApplicants(jobApplicationDataTable $dataTable){
         return $dataTable->render('employee.view-deployed-applicants');
    }
```

View:

```
<x-admin.admin-layout>
    <head>

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/bs4/dt-1.11.3/b-2.1.1/b-html5-2.1.1/date-1.1.1/r-2.2.9/datatables.min.css"/>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.36/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.36/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/bs4/dt-1.11.3/b-2.1.1/b-html5-2.1.1/date-1.1.1/r-2.2.9/datatables.min.js"></script>

    </head>
    <section class="content" style="margin-left: 18em; margin-top: 5em; margin-right: 2em;">
        <h3> Deployed Applicants </h3>
        <div class="row input-daterange">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <input type="date" name="from_date" id="from_date" class="form_control" placeholder="From">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <input type="date" name="to_date" id="to_date" class="form_control" placeholder="To">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <button type="button" name="filter" class="btn btn-success">Filter</button>
                <button type="button" name="refresh" class="btn btn-success">Refresh</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                {!! $dataTable->table() !!}
            </div>
        </div>
</x-admin.admin-layout>
```

I'm very new to datatables and I've been stuck here for hours. I have to add more features such as select records by to and from date, and export to pdf. But I have no idea where to start debugging. There aren't many resources on what I want to accomplish. What's wrong with my code? Is there a simpler way to approach this without the package?

Comment: I've never seen server-side HTML generation like this before, but I suppose the obvious first question is where does `$dataTable` come from in your view? I don't see it anywhere in  your code.

Comment: Hi, the $dataTable comes from the Controller 
`public function viewDeployedApplicants(jobApplicationDataTable $dataTable){
         return $dataTable->render('employee.view-deployed-applicants');
    }` 
(also included above after the web.php route)

Comment: That's an argument to the controller function, it's not getting sent to the view. Do you perhaps mean to do `return view('employee.view-deployed-applicants')->with(["dataTable" => $dataTable]);`

Comment: Doing that returns a `Call to undefined method App\DataTables\jobApplicationDataTable::table() `. This is the tutorial I followed:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZqPzSIK2N-Y
I'm rewatching it again, and I'm sure I followed everything.

Comment: I think you're missing including `<script src="{{ asset('vendor/datatables/buttons.server-side.js') }}"></script>` and `{{$dataTable->scripts()}}`  [Update app layout](https://yajrabox.com/docs/laravel-datatables/master/quick-starter#:~:text=Users_%27%20.%20date(%27YmdHis%27)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D-,Update%20app%20layout,-Add%20scripts%20before)